"All uploaded bundles must be signed." error while uploading app bundle to the internal testing release (and other releases) Android Play Console
I get "All uploaded bundles must be signed." error while uploading app bundle to the internal testing release (and other releases) in Android Play Console. I tried generating new keys, however app profile is fresh in the play console. My IDE is Android Studio. Any ideas? I didn't see any posts about my problem across the internet.

Have you read https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842756?hl=en

Yep I signed apk as described in the docs. Not working

Working now: I needed to add in the build.gradle (:app) debuggable false line in the buildTypes section
